# Cloud Hyperlink Warning Message

Tags: 2013, development, jquery, hyperlink

This has never happened to me before.  I have a hyperlink that I have added to a page.  I have added on the page, not in a list.  I add the link on the page without any problems.  Clicking on the link a window message box comes up telling me that

> I am leaving xxxxx site and not trusted.

The problem is that the site is not a untrusted site that would cause a message window to appear.

Tested solutions

1. Checked that the URLs were added to trusted site list
2. Added and removed the 's' in HTTP

Nothing is working.  Do you know why SharePoint is triggering a message window box?  How do I get it to go away?  A few things to note.  This does not happen with any other links on the page.  It is also a URL that is connected to cloud.  Any help would be helpful

**UPDATE:** if I paste the direct link into browser it works without the pop message coming up.  it only appears if the link is on sharepoint page as a texted hyperlink.

Comment: What's the warning message said? do you try to enable mixed content in your browser as I mentioned at https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/04/03/only-secure-content-is-displayed-allow-display-mixed-content/

Comment: @M.Qassas It said that I am leaving a (name of site) site and is not endorsed by the site.

Comment: Is it public URL? How you host it in your page?

Comment: No it is private.  I typed words on a page and added the link to the text.

Comment: Did you get the same message in other browsers? could you share the URL of your hyperlink without the  domain name?

Comment: No I  only have access to IE. When I add the link to links list a message does not appear.  When I add text and link the url to it the message comes up

Comment: Have a look at this. It might be IE Trusted Site issue https://www.technipages.com/ie-disable-current-web-page-is-trying

Comment: @SharePointer Already made sure the site was added to the trusted site list.  it only happens with this url. Noticed that it only happens if the url is on a page.  works fine is a links list.  odd.

Comment: Not sure but you can try add the domain in the Site Settings > HTML Field Security.  Just in case it is CORS issue.  Also, have you tired this on another computer/user?

Comment: @SharePointer Yes I have tried on another computer/user - it still happens.

Comment: @SharePointer It still appears after adding site to HTML Field Security.  Thanks for the idea